# drop one of the duplicate columns in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to drop only the first or last occurrence of the column "A". How do I do that?
The MWE below drops both columns of A.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCA'))
print (df)
df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1, inplace=True)
print (df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is create mask for match `A` and for duplicated - first or last values and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCA'))
print (df)
    A   B   C   A
0  66  92  98  17
1  83  57  86  97
2  96  47  73  32
3  46  96  25  83
4  78  36  96  80

m1 = df.columns == 'A'
m2 = df.columns.duplicated()
m3 = df.columns.duplicated(keep='last')

df1 = df.loc[:, (m1 & m2) | ~m1]
print (df1)
   B   C   A
0  92  98  17
1  57  86  97
2  47  73  32
3  96  25  83
4  36  96  80

df2 = df.loc[:, (m1 & m3) | ~m1]
print (df2)

    A   B   C
0  66  92  98
1  83  57  86
2  96  47  73
3  46  96  25
4  78  36  96
```

But if need only first duplicated columns:

```
df3 = df.loc[:, ~m2]
#last duplicated
df4 = df.loc[:, ~m3]
```

Comment: you could just pass it directly into loc without the m1  : df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated(keep='last')]. assumption of course is that the OP wants to keep only the first of the duplicate columns

Comment: @sammywemmy - Agree, but also OP need test `A`

Comment: @sammywemmy - But agree, like improve answer it it good idea, thank you